# Wolfram-Alpha closed form of product of Gamma function

Tags: gamma-function, products, wolfram-alpha

Wolfram-Alpha
recognizes this closed form
\begin{align} 
\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\sin(\pi k/n)
&=
2^{1-n}\,n
\end{align}
[just fine](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=product%28sin%28Pi*k%2Fn%29%2Ck%3D1..n-1%29%3B)

[image]

but fails 
[on this one](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=product%28Gamma%28k%2Fn%29%2Ck%3D1..n-1%29%3B),

[image]

despite that this expression also has a known closed form
\begin{align} 
\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\Gamma(k/n)
&=
\sqrt{\frac{ (2\,\pi)^{n-1}}{n}}
.
\end{align}

Question: Is there a way to make Wolfram-Alpha
to recognize it?

Comment: @g.kov: Mathematica is returning Indeterminate for that expression, which is likely the reason for WA not returning a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comment by @Moo, 
I checked that it is indeed the Mathematica's fault
and asked the [follow-up question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/209870/24614)
and get 
[a quick response](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/209872/24614)
on how to mitigate this. For some reason, a cosmetic change
of the expression
\begin{align}
\Gamma \left(\frac{k}{n}\right)
&=\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{k}{n}+1\right)}{\frac{k}{n}}
\end{align}

makes the 
Mathematica and hence, Wolfram happy:

[image]